# Aligning ducks and their labels in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, labels, trees, tikzducks

I'm building a tree of labelled tikzducks.
An MWE would be

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [level distance=4cm, sibling distance=4cm]
    \node {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \duck 
            \node [xshift=8, yshift=-25] at (wing) {Text};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    child { node {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \duck[signpost=1]
            \node [xshift=8, yshift=-25] at (wing) {Text};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    } }
    child { node {
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \duck[graduate=gray!20!black, tassel=red!70!black]
            \node [xshift=8, yshift=-25] at (wing) {Text};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    } };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting image is

[image]

Now, the ducks are not the same height (because of the hat), and I want them to be aligned at their bottom, so that the labels are level.
I tried yshifting the duck, but this didn't work

Bonus question: Do I need to offset the label off the (wing) position and what would be an easier way to position it centered under each duck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `forest` package is no so hard:

**Edit:** Above assumption is not completely correct. So far is very hard problem to correct include images in forest node.

**Edit:**
Considering of suggestion in the @Ulrike Fischer answer on [my question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596315/how-to-include-tikzpicture-in-forest-node) with added estimation of duck size:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest} 
for tree = {
            minimum size = 6.2em, % approximation of a ducks sizes
/tikz/every label/.style = {label distance=0pt, inner sep=0pt},
% tree settings
   anchor = south,
     edge = {-, semithick, shorten < = 1em, shorten > = 0.5em},
    s sep = 8mm,
    l sep = 16mm,
            }
[,tikz={\duck[shift=(.south west)]},
  label=below:Text (label), 
   [,tikz={\duck[shift=(.south west),signpost=1]},
     label=below:Text (label)] % processed
   [,tikz={\duck[shift=(.south west),%
           graduate=gray!20!black, tassel=red!70!black]},
    ,label=below:Text (label)]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oops, see that the signpost is empty? What's that?

Comment: indeed. It seems that `signpost` has a bug/misfeatures. Other options works as expected. I will investigate this at late evening.

Comment: you can't use \node in forest like this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, you are right. Unfortunately so far i didn't figure out, what is the right way. I will ask ne question about this.

Comment: @OlafMusch, thanks to Ulrike helps, now duck at below let node has number in signpost.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution [here](https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=347&id=96957#c96957). As far as I can tell, one should absolutely not nest `tikzpicture`s.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [level distance=4cm, sibling distance=4cm,
    hide/.style={opacity=0}]
    \node[matrix] {
            \duck[/tikz/local bounding box=d]
            \path (d.south) node [below] {Text};\\
    }
    child { node[matrix] {
            \duck[signpost=1,graduate=hide,tassel=hide,/tikz/local bounding box=d]
            \path (d.south) node [below] {Text};\\
    } }
    child { node[matrix] {
            \duck[graduate=gray!20!black, tassel=red!70!black,/tikz/local bounding box=d]
            \path (d.south) node [below] {Text};\\
    } };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]