# How to include `tikzpicture` in forest node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, tikzducks

How to include `tizpicture`, for example defined in `ducks` package, to a `forest` node?

**Edit:**
Simplified MWE with comparison result using `duck` in `tikzpicture` and in `forest`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline]{\duck[signpost=1]}\quad
    \begin{forest} 
[\tikz{\duck[signpost=1]}]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the duck image in forest node is not complete, missed is result of option `signpost=1`.

[image]

I guess, that image is included before its process of duck drawing is complete. So far I didn't find a way how to delay inclusion of image, or better, how to correct include such images in `forest` node.

Comment: Ducks can be nested in `pic`, did you try this option?

Comment: @SebGlav, no. I didn't. Can you show me, how to do this in `forest`?

Comment: The syntax would be `\draw pic[duck/signpost=1]{duck};`, leading to (in the forest node): `[\tikz{\draw pic[duck/signpost=1]{duck}}, label=below:Text]`. It works well out of the `forest` environment. But I just tried it into the forest node, and it fails too.

Comment: @SebGlav, unfortunately, this doesn't work correctly. On the duck table is still missed number one. This mean that include pic in such a way is not correct way. Something should be add to forest option that duck image will be correct processed. I don't know what.

Comment: Yes, like I said. Very annoying lack, even if we should not nest `tikz` inside forest nodes, in the first place.

Comment: +1 because it's duck-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add tikz pictures with the `tikz` key. But you will have to adapt the spacing and the positioning:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{ducks}

\begin{document}

    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
% nodes labels
/tikz/every label/.style = {label distance=0pt, inner sep=0pt},
% tree setings
    anchor = south,
     edge = {-, semithick, shorten < = 1em},
    s sep = 30mm,
    l sep = 30mm,
            }
[Text,tikz={\duck[shift=(.north)]},
   [Text,tikz={\duck[shift=(.north),signpost=1]}] % processed
   [Text,tikz={\duck[shift=(.south west),graduate=gray!20!black, tassel=red!70!black]},
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help (+1). With defining node size and adaptions of duck shifts, I manage toto draw tree as desired. See my answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/596228/aligning-ducks-and-their-labels-in-a-tree/596235#596235. I will wait a day or so, if some more answer will come.

Comment: @Zarko Now you can accept :).

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner, I just do. Recently days I was mostly off-line :-(

Comment: @Zarko Being offline is not always a bad thing :). I go offline now too :). See u.